# Is there a possibility to create a project inside a folder in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, subdirectory, directory-structure

is there a possibility to create a project inside a folder in eclipse?

I want to do something like this:

- workspace/basics/basic_project1
- workspace/basics/basic_project2
- workspace/basics/basic_project3
- workspace/algorithm/algorithm_project1
- workspace/algorithm/algorithm_project2
- workspace/skript/skript_project1
- workspace/project1
- workspace/project2

I want to have a folder structure in which I have the folders as example basics, scripts and algorithm in which I can do projects which belonging to this categories.

So if I start programming and I don't know something, I wouldn't close the workspace and open another workspace and I wouldn't search in the web.

I think I have so much basic programs and algorithm of different kinds, which I want to use again. But I want to easy select them in the folder view of eclipse.

I know that I can create different projects for this, but I want to collect them in a folder that the package explorer is clearer. So I want to create a folder structure in which the basics or things I think I can use multiple times is stored in different folders, but in the same workspace.

I hope you can understand my question and I hope you can help me. Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to organizing multiple projects, working sets might be useful.
`Right click on project -> Assign Working Sets -> fill in the dialogs`. For above example you would have working sets for basics, algorithms, scripts. The final two would end unassigned to any of the sets. Remember - there is no directory structure on filesystem, if you have not specified custom locations (that's below). It's only *logical* aggregation.

Filesystem directory structure is another story - while creating new (Java) project you can uncheck `Use default location` part and put in your directory structure. Together with working sets that should cover your requirements.